# classifying work folders and data, any recommended structure?

Tags: data, productivity

As my research and fields if interest change over time I came to build a vast amount of research drafts, data files, different academic and non academic reports and publications. The same thing for talks, trainings, statements and institutions related paperworks.

My question: Is there any standard way of classifying academic files? folders structure, files and draft naming ?

If there is not, what are the general rules you apply when classifying your files. and do you use any software for this propose.

Comment: Libraries use the Dewey system...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other possibilities, I know, but most will fail at a certain level of complexity. Think instead about how the WWW (World Wide Web) is "organized". Basically it isn't we use search to find things. Google indexes things in complex ways to make search fast. But the MACOS (and I assume others) do something similar with files that it can reach. If you can keep a vast amount of information "online" search will find it.

You can aid search, of course, by "tagging" your files with one or more of several standard (to you) keywords, much as the tags on this site are used to help users find questions of interest.

Likewise, if an OS allows alias "files" you can also "file" aliases of important files in some complex directory structure, but it takes work to design it and to keep it rational over time.

And, of course, keep everything backed up.